# Email is not appearing in "TO" field

Tags: android, email

In the app that I am developing, in the settings-->about-->I have a button which says "contact us", this button is supposed to send an email from the user to me.

This is my code:

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.about_app);

        ImageButton email=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.email_imbtn);
        email.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
                intent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:")); // only email apps will handle this
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, getString(R.string.email_address));
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, getString(R.string.app_name));

                if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null)
                {
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
                else
                    Toast.makeText(About.this,  "משהו השתבש בניסיון פתיחת תוכנת האימייל", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
```

The email is not appearing in the "TO" field

[image]

How can I fix it?

Comment: You haven't shown the full path from the moment you have an email address string to the moment you populate the UI.  There could be many things going wrong in between.

Comment: this is the whole relevant code, and @Elvis Chweya fixed my problem. thanks anyway..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
intent.setData(Uri.fromParts("mailto", getString(R.string.to_email_address), null));
```

Instead of

```
intent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:"));
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you missed adding receiver name name in mail to

Set the receiver email as below

intent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:" + "recipient@example.com"));

Answer (score 1):

I use following code to send an email from my app.

```
mailMe.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
              public void onClick(View paramAnonymousView) {
                  Intent emailActivity = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);

                    emailActivity.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, getResources().getString(R.string.email));

                    emailActivity.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, getResources().getString(R.string.app_name));

                    //you can specify cc addresses as well
                    // email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_CC, new String[]{ ...});
                    // email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_BCC, new String[]{ ... });

                    //set up the message body
                    //emailActivity.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message);

                    emailActivity.setType("message/rfc822");
                    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailActivity, "Complete action using"));
              }
        });
```

Hope this will help someone.